# The MongoDB stuck when trying to post a new form data with photo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**server.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));
app.use(express.json())
```

**controllers/user.js**

```
export const registerUser = async(req,res) => {
    try{
        const { name, email, password, phone, address, answer } = req.fields
        const { photo } = req.files

        if (!name) {
            return res.send({ message: "Name Is Required!" });
        }
        if (!email) {
            return res.send({ message: "Email Is Required!" });
        }
        if (!password) {
            return res.send({ message: "Password Is Required!" });
        }
        if (!phone) {
            return res.send({ message: "Phone Number Is Required!" });
        }
        if (!answer) {
            return res.send({ message: "Answer Is Required!" });
        }

        const existingUser = await userModel.findOne({ email })
        if(existingUser) {
            return res.send({
                success: false,
                message: "This email already registered. Please use another one"
            })
        }

        const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password)

        const user = new userModel({
            name, email, phone, address, answer,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        if(photo){
            user.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(photo.path)
            user.photo.contentType = photo.type
        }

        await user.save()

        res.status(201).send({
            success: true,
            message: "User registered success",
            user 
        })
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error)
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: "Error in registration",
            error 
        })
    }
}
```

**models/userModel.js**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true 
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        phone: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        address: {
            type: {}
        },
        photo: {
            data: Buffer,
            contentType: String,
        },
        answer: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        role: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

export default mongoose.model("Users", userSchema)
```

I am not sure does MongoDB limit the storage size when I trying to post a new form data with photo field. It returns success when I submitted a new form data but when trying to load the MongoDB database it got stuck. Any solutions to expand the storage size to overcome the issue?

Comment: _"... does MongoDB limit the storage size"_  Yes, the [_"The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes."_](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-BSON-Document-Size) _"... when trying to load the MongoDB database it got stuck."_  Would you clarify what you mean?  Are you sure it's MongoDB that is not responding? _"Any solutions to expand the storage size ...?"_  You might want to look at [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/), a MongoDB _"specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB."_